# Blender 3d maps

Tags: 3d-view

I ask for help in clarifying. I have 2 head models, low poly and high poly. I baked a normal map from HP to LP and connected it to LP. Everything is fine here. In addition to the normal map, I want to connect the Roughness Map to LP. I did the following algorithm: unfolded HP, created a texture and applied a texture brush to roughness on the HP model. Baking in the Image texture and connecting it to the LP did nothing (on the created texture, the background is completely black, i.e. the roughness is 100%). I have two questions:

Should I draw the Roughness Map texture already on Low poly? Why then bake it?
What about other cards? (AO, SSS, diffuse). Are they also drawn on low poly?

Answer (score 0):

Any map that you want to bake from High poly to Low you can connect to Emission Shader node, then bake Emit:

[image]

It's the easiest way.

I could also recommend some add-ons which could automate the process, like [easyBake](https://github.com/leukbaars/EasyBake)

Comment: Does that add-on still work in 3.0? I'm not OP, just someone who saw your answer and is interested. :)

Comment: I haven't tried, but last change is 4 m old, should be maintained.

Comment: I gave it a quick test and it seems to work in 3.0.  Had trouble installing it so just downloaded the script and ran it.